# Limit result number on genre/artist request

Tags: deezer

I would like to have Electro artists but when I do this request:
https://api.deezer.com/genre/106/artists?limit=500

I only got a limited result nomber no matter what the number (500 here ) is .

which is not the case when I do this request:
https://api.deezer.com/playlist/4341978/tracks?limit=1000

Is That normal?

or did I make a mistake on my request ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try limits that are smaller? A lot of APIs have an upper limit above which they won't return (there are several reasons they do this).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there is only a limit amount of artists under genre 106, you cant return more than exist!

Answer (score 0):

The limit paramater is not available on the genre/{id}/artists api call. This method will always return a list of 50 artists.